# How to check if the selected text in RichTextBox has bold style

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have a toolbar in my `C#` application which in there is a `B` button to change my RicheTextBox selected text style. I want to set `Checked` property of this button to `true`, if the selected text has **bold** style.

SO is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I could check the text **bold** style

```
private void rch_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tlButton.Checked = rch.SelectionFont.Bold;
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, it is really hardly valuable enough content to justify a self-answered question, imo.

Comment: @TaW So are you suggesting me to remove the answer, letting others answer the question, or removing the whole Q&A?

Comment: I think other programmers would find the answer useful. Sometimes it is as simple as overlooking an existing property.